# How to call a method on vue component after it rendered in storybook?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

My problem was to call a method **after** the component has rendered in storybook. It is about showing a modal, but it can be applied to any vue component.
I need here to call to the method `showDialog(true)` **after** the creation of the component to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tricky solution using Typescript with the [component story format of storybook (version 5.2+)](https://storybook.js.org/docs/formats/component-story-format/) :

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

// ... some imports and global setup 

export const normalError = () => ({
  components: { 'error-modal': ErrorModal },
  template: `<error-modal @hook:mounted='externalMount'/>`, // bind the custom method on mounted hook
  methods: {                           // bind the new method to the component
    async externalMount() {            // don't use an arrow function or this will have wrong scope
      const anyThis: any = this;
      const vm = anyThis.$children[0]; // target the component ErrorModal
      await Vue.nextTick();            // wait that mounted() finished
      vm.showDialog(true);             // finally show the modal / call the method !
    }
  }
});
```

If you find a better one, I would be glad to know and upvote it.

Comment: The $children instance property has been removed from Vue 3.0 and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from our project using storybook 6.1. It executes code when the component has been **mounted**

```
<Preview>
  <Story name="The equipment">
  {
    {
      components: { EquipmentView },
      template: `<EquipmentView />`,
      mounted () {
        this.$store.commit('equipmentStore/setSelectedEquipment', {
          equipmentId: 'CONT100A',
          equipmentName: 'Container 100L A',
        });
      }
    }
  }
  </Story>
</Preview>
```

for this Vue(x) component

```
export default class EquipmentView extends Vue {
    private storeModule = getModule(EquipmentStore);
    ...
}
```

I would like typescript support in the storybook even more (maybe someone can add an answer for that).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it (in `mdx` format, there should be an equivalent for CSF)

```js
export const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { ModalComponent },
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  mounted () {
    this.$children[0].open()
  },
  template: `
    <ModalComponent v-bind="$props">
      <template #header>Header</template>
      <template #body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</template>
      <template #footer>Footer</template>
    </ModalComponent>
  `
 });
```

Comment: The $children instance property has been removed from Vue 3.0 and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Because Vue3 has removed the $children property, now one needs to use the refs instead.

```
export const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { ModalComponent },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.MY_REF.componentFunction();
    });
  },
  template: `<ModalComponent v-bind="args" ref="MY_REF">`
 });
```